# How does $\|\Delta u\, \vec{r}_u \times \Delta v \,\vec{r}_v \| = \|\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v \|\,\Delta u \,\Delta v$?

Tags: surface-integrals, cross-product

> The cross product $a \times b$ is defined as a vector $c$ that is perpendicular (orthogonal) to both $a$ and $b,$ with a direction given by the right-hand rule and a magnitude equal to the area of the parallelogram that the vectors span.

I have trouble understanding why $\|\vec{r}_u \,\Delta u \times  \vec{r}_v \, \Delta v\| = \|\vec{r}_u \times  \vec{r}_v \| \, \Delta u \, \Delta v $ where the $\text{“}\|\text{''}$ denotes vector norm and $\times$ is the cross product. **I'm not understanding how vector norms preserve closure under scalar multiplication.**

How do we prove that $\|\Delta u \, \vec{r}_u \times \Delta v \,\vec{r}_v \| = \|\vec{r}_u  \times  \vec{r}_v\| \, \Delta u \, \Delta v$?

I think $ r_u, r_v$ are vectors  $ \in \mathbb{R^3 }$ and $\Delta u, \Delta v \in \mathbb{R}$?

Is $\Delta u \cdot \Delta v \in \mathbb{R}$ and the product of two real numbers?

For context, I saw the equality $\|\vec{r}_u \, \Delta u \times  \vec{r}_v \, \Delta v\| = \|\vec{r}_u  \times  \vec{r}_v \| \, \Delta u \, \Delta v$ below for calculating surface integrals and the derivation of the volume element:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I edited to change $||\vec{r_u} \Delta u \times  \vec{r_v} \Delta v\| = \|\vec{r_u} \times  \vec{r_v} \| \, \Delta u \Delta v$ to $\|\vec{r}_u \,\Delta u \times  \vec{r}_v \, \Delta v\| = \|\vec{r}_u \times  \vec{r}_v \| \, \Delta u \, \Delta v$ and the like. Note that things like $||A||$ were changed to $\|A\|$, things like $\vec{r_u}$ to $\vec{r}_u,$ and a small space was inserted before and after $\Delta u$ and $\Delta v$ whenever something preceded or followed that (and "something" does not include $\times$ or $\|,$ etc.). $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes $\Delta u$ and $\Delta v$ are scalar quantities.

Indeed by definition:

$$\vec a \times \vec b = (a_yb_z-a_zb_y)\hat e_1 + (a_zb_x-a_xb_z)\hat e_2 + (a_xb_y-a_yb_x)\hat e_3$$

therefore:

$$s\vec a \times t\vec b = st(a_yb_z-a_zb_y)\hat e_1 + st(a_zb_x-a_xb_z)\hat e_2 + st(a_xb_y-a_yb_x)\hat e_3=st(\vec a \times \vec b)$$

Comment: Is the vector norm closed under scalar multiplication? Like |$6 \vec{u} \times 7 \vec{v} |$ = 42 $|\vec{u} \times \vec{v}|$? where "$||"$ denotes the vector norm?

Comment: scalar quantities can be factored out as for the dot product, it's an immediate consequence of definition

Comment: Why is the surface element |$r_u \times r_v|$ $\Delta u$ $\Delta v$ rather than simply |$r_u \times r_v$| without $\Delta u$ $\Delta v$? |$r_u \times r_v$| gives us the area of a parallelogram. Why do we also need to multiply the area of the parallelogram by $\Delta u  \Delta v$? Does both $\Delta u$ and $\Delta v$ vary at each tiny patch of the of the surface?

Comment: partial derivatives are unitary vectors, you need to multiply by the side's length to find the area

Comment: So $\Delta u$, $\Delta v$ accounts for the sides length. |$ r_u \times r_v$ | fails to account for area? But the area of a parallelogram is the magnitude of the cross product of two vectors, how would |$ r_u \times r_v$ | fail to account for area? $\Delta u$, $\Delta v$ are scaling factors? So the surface element which equals $|r_u \times r_v| \Delta u \Delta v$ isn't constant throughout the surface?

Comment: Yes they account for the direction.